# How do you find N integers such that their sum equals to M?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

How do you find any possible combination of N **distinct** integers such that their sum equals to a given integer M?

The integers can be between -2^31 to 2^31, with N being less than or equal to 500000 and M also being between -2^31 and 2^31.

An example:

- 4 is given as N, 8 is given as M.
- A possible combination would be 3, -1, 4, 2

Comment: 3 - 1 + 4 - 2 is not equal to 8, or am I missing something?

Comment: What have *YOU* tried so far? Share your ideas / code.

Comment: I may have mistyped it, sorry for the error

Comment: With N=2 and M=0 there are already 2**31 solutions. Is it realy what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say `N` is odd. We can choose `N/2` positive integers that are not M. We also choose the negative of those integers. Finally, we choose `M`. For example, if `N = 5` and `M = 9`, we can choose `2, -2, 4, -4`. Then we simply choose `9`, as our final integer, giving us a sum of `M`.

Let's say `N` is even. We can use a similar system, but choose `N/2-1` positive integers and their negative counterparts, `0`, and then `M`. So for `N = 6`, `M = 11`, we can choose `5, -5, 6, -6, 0, 11` for a sum of `11`.

These choices are not unique, but simply choosing consecutive integers would be trivial.

Comment: I never thought of a solution similar to that, thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: @WillardSun if this solves your problem. consider marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Fours integers you have provided into the questions don't add up to 8.
2. As you have not mentioned in the question, I am assuming that duplicates are allowed. What you can do is to divide `M` into `N-1` equal segments (floor division) and Nth element will be `M - M/(N-1) * (N-1)`

```
def findCombination(N, M):
   if N == 1:
      return M
   ans = [(M/(N-1)) * (N-1)]
   ans.append(M - M/(N-1) * (N-1))
   return ans
```

**Update:**
As of now, the question has been updated that only distinct elements are allowed, you can follow the process:

1. If `N` is odd:
   start picking up values with the same absolute value but with different signs like `1 -1 2 -2 3 -3`. Don't include M in this process. You can choose `N/2` positive elements and `N/2` negative elements. The last element you can include in and is `M`.
2. If `N` is even:
   start picking values as described above. Now you need to exclude two elements which sum up to `M`. So you can exclude `1` and `M-1` and later include them into final answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Didn't realise haha

Comment: Also duplicates are not allowed, they should be distinct integers, sorry for the error

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code in GO

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    n, m := 15, 10

    fmt.Println(m)

    if n == 1 {
        return
    }

    n--

    if n%2 != 0 {
        fmt.Println(0)
        n--
    }

    for i := 1; i < n; i += 2 {
        fmt.Println(-i)
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

}
```